# How do I get rid of the Bitstream Vera font in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-font-family

I installed Google Chrome from the Google download page. I went to chrome://settings/fonts , and I changed the default font to Ubuntu, but that only changed some websites. Chrome still uses Bitstream Vera for a lot of websites, despite the fact that I changed the default font to Ubuntu. How do I *completely* change the font to Ubuntu? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Clay: some websites may be explicitly requesting "serif" or another font that does not map to "sans-serif/Ubuntu".  Is that the case?

Comment: Each site that has Bitstream requests Arial first, then sans-serif. Might Bitstream possibly be being used as a substitute for Arial? If so, how do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing Bitstream Charter in the Fonts menu, in the Settings. Can you verify?

You see Bitstream Charter simply because the font name comes first in the list.
I think the browser font is not specified in this location; rather, the browser obtains the default font settings from Ubuntu.